# Access is denied in windows cmd.Why?

Tags: cmd

`a.txt` and `b.txt` are text files and `in_red.exe` is a program that takes in input as characters and outputs characters till `EOF` is reached.I am the admin of the system.
Also,windows gives a popup saying this app isin't available in your PC.

```
    C:\Users\Aryamaan Jain\Desktop\io_redir>dir /b
    a.txt
    b.txt
    in_red.exe

    C:\Users\Aryamaan Jain\Desktop\io_redir>in_red.exe < a.txt >b.txt
    Access is denied.
```

Comment: Did you try running `cmd.exe` as an administrator?

Comment: Tried, access is still denied.

Comment: I have similarly found the same issue with redirectors.. can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long search,I found out that the program `in_red.exe` got corrupted(became of size 0kb) for some reason I don't know. However, I replaced the program and now the command is working perfectly.

Comment: did you figure out why the redirectors corrupted your executable? I've just had the same issue after trying to redirect my executable output to a txt file..

Answer (score 2):

Access is denied as you are not the owner of the folder where you are trying to execute the command. To get ownership of the folder please follow the following steps:

1. Right click folder
2. Select "Properties"
3. Select the "Security" tab
4. Click the "Advanced" button
5. Select the "Owner" tab
6. Click the "Edit" button
7. Under 'Change owner to' highlight the user you wish to set as owner
8. Check the 'Replace owner on subcontainers and objects' box
9. Click the 'Apply' button

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 'Norton' antivirus was blocking the file write because it was trying to write stdout in a file by kubectl.exe

Answer (score -1):

Look at the following issues

1. You have a personal firewall installed. Try uninstalling it.
2. You have not logged in as an administrator, try to login as an administrator.
3. You can also check by right clicking `c:\windows\system32` folder or `c:\windows\system32\ipconfig.exe` and selecting Properties. Click on the security tab and check for the permission for users. Make sure that the Read & Execute permission is on.
4. If the above steps don't work, you can right click on `C:` (the OS partition), add your account and replace permissions of all the child objects.

Comment: The question makes no sense and neither does this answer. Uninstalling the firewall and removing system protection is a bad suggestion and has nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani i know uninstalling firewall is bad ,but these are the only possible cases which leads to above error message.

Comment: No it is not. Asker says he has admin access, he is working with files in Desktop directory where he has full access. "Access is denied" can appear for many reasons, including bogus command line arguments such as foo.exe <x>y. And what could this possibly have to do with ipconfig.exe?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani i have only described  the possible list of issues/causes,which the user have to check.

Comment: I turned off my firewall for 10 minutes, to see if it works - and it did! I had to manually add all commands, but eventually my network is secure and I'm happy. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Run it as administrator to prevent Google showing a snap error:

```
REG ADD “HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome” /v RendererCodeIntegrityEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```